# One of the nodes is not showing its health status

Tags: weblogic, soa

In the `weblogic console`, one of the nodes are not showing their health status while admin server and other nodes are showing there health status as "OK".

Is there any issue regarding communication between `admin server` and `managed server` or some other reason for this node not showing a health status?

What should be done?

Comment: Very strange, maybe post a screenshot of the node with missing health status?  That might pose a clue as to why there is no health status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to get the status of managed server by restarting the managed server only.
it seems it is the problem due to unstability of the environment.there was problem with the start argument of the managed server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks like a communication issue between Admin and Managed server. What you can usually do is:

1. Restart all. Then start Admin first and wait till its on. Then start the Managed server. Does the problem still persist?
2. Check that the Managed server is started properly. See that there are no errors in the log file.
3. Check the logs of the managed server. See if the managed server complains about not being able to connect to Admin, otherwise there should be a log message saying that the connection with the Admin was established.
4. You can also start Managed server without starting the Admin server, see if the Managed server is trying to contact the Admin server or not.
5. Check the `config.xml` file of the Admin and Managed server. Check the node and servers definitions, check their IP addresses, ports, etc.